# android service aidl method put data to LinkedBlockingQueue ,take data from workerthread wrong

Tags: android, multithreading, aidl

I'm using android aidl. I have a method to put data into a queue, and a read thread to take data from it.

```
private static LinkedBlockingQueue<int[]> mWriteQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<int[]>();

private final ISendService.Stub mBinder = new ISendService.Stub() {
@Override
public void writeData(int[] data) throws RemoteException {
    try {
            mWriteQueue.put(data);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private class WriteThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            try {
                int[] data = mWriteQueue.take();
Log.e(TAG, "mWriteQueue take:" + ByteUtils.toHexString(data));
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the UI, a button is clicked to execute the code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    try {
        mSendService.writeData(data);
        Log.e(TAG, "write data:" + ByteUtils.toHexString(data));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
}
```

the result:

```
write data:0x51 0x51 0x01 0x08
write data:0x51 0x51 0x02 0x08
write data:0x51 0x51 0x03 0x08
write data:0x51 0x51 0x04 0x08
write data:0x51 0x51 0x05 0x08
write data:0x51 0x51 0x06 0x08
write data:0x51 0x51 0x07 0x08
write data:0x51 0x51 0x08 0x08
write data:0x51 0x51 0x09 0x08
write data:0x51 0x51 0x0a 0x08


mWriteQueue take:0x51 0x51 0x01 0x08
mWriteQueue take:0x51 0x51 0x0a 0x08
mWriteQueue take:0x51 0x51 0x0a 0x08
mWriteQueue take:0x51 0x51 0x0a 0x08
mWriteQueue take:0x51 0x51 0x0a 0x08
mWriteQueue take:0x51 0x51 0x0a 0x08
mWriteQueue take:0x51 0x51 0x0a 0x08
mWriteQueue take:0x51 0x51 0x0a 0x08
mWriteQueue take:0x51 0x51 0x0a 0x08
mWriteQueue take:0x51 0x51 0x0a 0x08
```

The data from `take` is wrong, I see in the java doc, that `take` should remove the item. I print the data before `mWriteQueue.put(data);` to make sure data is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I feel ashamed.
I resolved this problem.
thank Jade Emperor.
use 
    mWriteQueue.put(data.clone());